# Merging two or more .wav files in android

Tags: android

First of all I must tell you that I am new to android. I want to combine two .wav (audio file) files. I have googled about it , it is easy to combine them using javax package  but it is not supported on android. Can you tell me how to do this in android. Can you suggest me any tutorial or library that can help?
Thanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by combine, exactly? Concatenate? Overlay?

Comment: @tomfanning Hi . Can you help to overlap two .wav files.